# Hiding text that is not in its own tag, but not an image in the same parent tag

Tags: css, hide

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="wrapper">
  <img src="..." />
  Some text!
</span>
```

How can I hide the text, but not the image, when the text doesn't have it's own tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position relative, perhaps:

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" />
  Some text!
</span>


.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: -9999px;
}

.wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    left: 9999px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qzva/)

Answer (score 0):

There's only so much CSS can do.

```
.wrapper {
  color: transparent;
}
```

I suppose you can mess with font sizes and families if you really wanted to but that's just messy.

Comment: OK, so this seems not to move other things over, like a `display:none` would. Do I need to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: Using JavaScript would involve wrapping the text in an element or removing the text from the element.

Answer (score 0):

try used `text-indent` to hide the text

```
 .wrapper {
      text-indent:-5000px;
    }
```

or `span` the text and have a unique `class` and `display:none`

html

```
<span class="wrapper">
  <img src="..." />
  <span>Some text!</span>
</span>
```

css

```
.wrapper span {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, your code is not proper. You are inserting an inline-block element(inline behaving as a block) within an inline element (span).
You can have following markup and make it easy:

```
<p>
  <img src=""/>
  <span></span>
</p>
```

And then easily hide the span. :)